# reloading the contents on a php page after changing data from xml file

Tags: php, html, xml

Hi so I am trying to create a backend page to delete some items in an xml file. everything works except for teh fact that once I press delete it take me to a new blank page. When i tried adding readfile(invneotrphp.php) it was not reading the entire code on my inventory php page

```
php to delete the contents from the XML file

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $dname= $_POST['name'];
    $xpath=new DOMXPATH($xml);
foreach($xpath->query("/products/p[name='$dname']") as $node)
    {
        $node-> parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    echo readfile("inventoryPHP.php");
    $xml->save("products.xml");
}
```

```
my main php file where I have my html
 <tbody>
                            <!--Tomatoes-->
                            <?php
                            $xml=simplexml_load_file('products.xml') ;
                            $counter=0;                          
                         
                            foreach($xml as $p){
                                $name=$xml-> p[$counter]->name;
                                $price=$xml-> p[$counter]->price;
                                $stock=$xml-> p[$counter]->stock;
                                $counter=$counter+1;                             

                            echo "<div>
                                <tr>

                                    <td>$counter</td>
                                    <td> <img src='$name.jpg' alt='$name' style='width:100px;height:100px'></td>
                                    <td>$name </td>
                                   
                                    <td>$price / lbs</td>
                                    <td>
                                    $stock 
                                      </td>
                                       <td>
                                       <form method='POST' action='add_delete.php'>
                                       <input type='submit' name='delete'  value='delete' /> 
                                       <input type='hidden' name='name' value='$name'/>
                                        </td>
                                        </form> 
                                </tr>
                            </div>   ";
                            }
                            ?>            
                            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a push system but PHP is not the best language for that. You can use Node JS instead.

Another way to do that is to do a AJAX request in intervals. There are many tutorials on that, just search for "AJAX JS" or "XMLHttpRequest JS".

I hope I could help you

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax and then use preventDefault() inbuilt function, it will prevent loading whole page and refresh only the content, for detail search about this function on google or youtube